# How to add a quarter to a date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way in oracle to add a quarter to a date.

For e.g 28-FEB-21 should become 28-MAY-20

Currently i am using ADD_MONTHS('28-FEB-21',3) to add a quarter but its changing the date to 31-MAY-21

Regards,

Comment: What should the result be when you add a quarter to `30-NOV-2019`?

Comment: If I add months to a date in the year 2021, why should the resulting date have the year 2020? Shouldn't that be: _For e.g 28-FEB-21 should become 28-MAY-21_ ?

Comment: Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html#GUID-B8C74443-DF32-4B7C-857F-28D557381543) is your friend: _If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same day component as date._

Comment: Two side observations. First, add_months takes a DATE, and you are giving it a STRING. This forces oracle to first do an implied to_date on your string. Never a good idea. Second, why are you re-creating the Y2K bug by using 2-digit years?  To address both issues, your code should be "add_months(to_date('21-Feb-2021','dd-Mon-yyyy'),3)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
LEAST(
  ADD_MONTHS( value, 3 ),
  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( value, 'MM' ), 3 )
    + ( value - TRUNC( value, 'MM' ) ) DAY TO SECOND
)
```

So, if you have the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-11-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-28' + INTERVAL '01:23:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Then the query:

```sql
SELECT value,
       LEAST(
         ADD_MONTHS( value, 3 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( value, 'MM' ), 3 )
           + ( value - TRUNC( value, 'MM' ) ) DAY TO SECOND
       ) AS value_plus_quarter
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE               | VALUE_PLUS_QUARTER 
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 2019-11-30 00:00:00 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00
> 2021-02-28 01:23:45 | 2021-05-28 01:23:45
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=180444e463e1fdb3707867f254259c3b)*